# Why does RestTemplate not bind response representation to PagedResources?

Tags: json, spring, rest, spring-data, spring-data-rest

I am using spring-data-rest to expose entities as (paged) rest resources. Everything works fine, but when I request data via `RestTemplate`, I get an useless HATEOAS JSON (which I didn't ask for). The JSON seems to be a PagedResources. I could live with that, but the JSON isn't converted into an object correctly. There is no `content` inside.

Repository:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "people", path = "people")
public interface PersonRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Person, Long>
{
    List<Person> findByLastName(@Param("name") String name);
}
```

Client:

```
public List<Person> getPersons()
{
    RestTemplate rt = new RestTemplate();
    System.out.println(rt.getForObject(URL, PagedResources.class).getContent().size());
    System.out.println(rt.getForObject(URL, PagedResources.class).getLinks().size());
    System.out.println(rt.getForObject(URL, PagedResources.class).getMetadata().getTotalElements());
    return new ArrayList<Person>(rt.getForObject(URL, PagedResources.class).getContent()); // <-- empty
}
```

System.out:

```
0 // getContent().size()
4 // getLinks().size()
2 // getTotalElements()
```

curl:

```
C:\...>curl http://localhost:8080/spring-jsf-rest/rest/people
{
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/spring-jsf-rest/rest/people{?page,size,sort}",
      "templated" : true
    },
    "search" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/spring-jsf-rest/rest/people/search"
    }
  },
  "_embedded" : {
    "people" : [ {
      "firstName" : "John",
      "lastName" : "Rambo",
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/spring-jsf-rest/rest/people/1"
        }
      }
    }, {
      "firstName" : "Chuck",
      "lastName" : "Norris",
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/spring-jsf-rest/rest/people/2"
        }
      }
    } ]
  },
  "page" : {
    "size" : 20,
    "totalElements" : 2,
    "totalPages" : 1,
    "number" : 0
  }
}
```

It seems like `_embedded` is not mapped correctly to content?!

Comment: Going forward you might wanna rethink the way you're asking questions here. If stuff is useless to you, don't use it. Please don't claim, you didn't ask for things if you're clearly issuing a `GET` request. As usual with computers, you *exactly* get what you ask for. If you don't specify an `Accept` header, you get the default, which is `application/hal+json`. Generally speaking such negative tone, doesn't create incentives to answer. Nonetheless, I took the time. You're most welcome. PS: What is an HATEOAS JSON, btw?

Comment: @Oliver: i admit, my tone is kind of negative. but those little obstacles get annoying. of course i tried other accept headers but the result is always the same. and im not the only one having trouble with this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/23264044/3563584 . also i didnt choose to use stuff, i have to.

Comment: Ahhhh so that's how you parse an _embedded list on the client, telling RestTemplate to expect one of the hateoas Resources classes.  Very useful, the spring-data-rest documentation is rather sparse on the client side

Answer (score 55, accepted):

As you've discovered correctly, `PagedResources` does not have an `_embedded` property, that's why you don't get the `content` property populated.

This dilemma can be solved in two different ways:

1. Providing a type that matches the representation in the first place. Thus, craft a custom class and either stick to the property names of the representation or customize it using Jackson annotations etc.
2. Set up a custom `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` and customize the `ObjectMapper`to get the `Jackson2HalModule` configured that Spring HATEOAS ships out of the box.

   ```
   ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
   mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
   mapper.registerModule(new Jackson2HalModule());

   MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
   converter.setSupportedMediaTypes(MediaType.parseMediaTypes("application/hal+json"));
   converter.setObjectMapper(mapper);

   RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate(Collections.<HttpMessageConverter<?>> singletonList(converter));
   ```

Comment: big thanks for your help. option 2 looks nice. but i get "Unrecognized field "templated" (class org.springframework.hateoas.Link), not marked as ignorable (one known property: "href"])". i guess i have to dig deeper. if i cant get it to work, i guess ill stick to option 1.

Comment: I think you can simply get rid off this by setting `objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);`. Jackson is quite strict by default. Updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Hm, if I do that [things break for me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49610391/pagedresources-content-array-is-empty) - any idea?

Comment: @OliverDrotbohm I am having the same issue, the difference is I am not using RestTemplate instead I am using FeignClient. What can I do?