# Remove HATEOS from spring data rest?

Tags: spring-data-rest, spring-hateoas

Is it possible to remove HATEOS from spring data rest?

What I want to do is just retrieve plain JSON from spring since I also need to get the values from a nested class.

Comment: You can subclass `RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration` and use it to customize your output. have a look on this question. http://stackoverflow.com/q/23264044/1660192