# How to load relationship Entity with Spring Rest Data

Tags: java, angularjs, rest, hateoas

I'm working in my learn project with AngularJS and Spring Rest Data.
I have the database tables Reservation and Client, a Reservation has a Client, perfect ... the JSON response for a Reservation query is the next:
[image: rest api response for reservation]

In yellow, it's the Client URL reference, I want to know if there any way to load this Client object to the response, some like the Jackson way (load the object and the intern object data, not a link), I know that it's the way with Spring Rest Data, but I'm confused by the way in that I should do this.

In my Angular Controller I have this:
[image]

And, in the view (I wish .. ) I load the client data, but obviously not have data (because I didn't query the client link)

[image]

The client view (table) looks like this (client data not shown)
[image]

Please help me :) Thanks a lot!

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23264044/spring-data-rest-disable-hypertext-application-language-hal-in-json-applica) is link to similar problem. You have to disable HAL media type.

Answer (score 2):

You can use @Projection class to get relationship table data. Projection class allow change JSON response format. As below picture, I can get project's data related with sprint.

[image]

I create SprintProjection class:

[image]

And I add projection class to Repository:

[image]

Here is source code sample: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/tree/master/rest/projections

Comment: Looks very well, I'll try, and show the result. Thanks!