# Pagingandsortingrepositrory in spring data , primary key in the entity is not present in the response

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, spring-hateoas, spring-repositories

I have declared pagingandSortingRepository for a JPA entity and the response to findall() is below

```
"_embedded" : {
    "assetDashboardCustomers" : [ {
      "utilization" : "80",
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/utilbycustomer/Customer01"
        },
        "assetDashboardCustomer" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/utilbycustomer/Customer01"
        }
      }
    },
```

I do not want _links and self [HATEOAS] details, but just the plain JSON.
What is the property I should set so that I get a plain JSON in the response

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23264044/disable-hypertext-application-language-hal-in-json

Comment: If you want ti include ID for a resource then you can enable this in  org.springframework.data.rest.core.config.RepositoryRestConfiguration

Comment: I followed the steps in the question, but only the content type in the header changes and not the actual JSON content

Comment: The first comment answers your first question - you cannot turn off the links. The second comment  answers you 2nd question which is how to have the ID in the JSON body.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, I configured to display the Ids.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `The first comment answers your first question - you cannot turn off
>   the links. The second comment answers you 2nd question which is how to
>   have the ID in the JSON body.`

--- By Alan hay in the comments