# How do I avoid extra json from getting records using CrudRepository

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, crud

I am using `CrudRepository` in spring boot application. It works fine but I am getting extra json attribute `_links`. How do I skip that extra json, as it's affecting on render large json object.

i am getting this kind of `json` format in response;

```
    {
  "_embedded": {
    "userses": [
      {
        "user_name": "john doe",
        "_links": {
          "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/userses/47375"
          },
          "users": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/userses/47375"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "user_name": "john1 doe1",
        "_links": {
          "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/userses/21665"
          },
          "users": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/userses/21665"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "user_name": "remmya1 decruize1",
        "_links": {
          "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/userses/47876"
          },
          "users": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/userses/47876"
          }
        }
      }
}
```

how do i neglect that extra part in json.

Comment: Could you provide a bit more information, maybe some piece of code? Or an example of what you want as opposed to what you are getting? Look at [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @SBylemans i have updated this post with the response i m getting as output. i guess it explains well my concern.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23264044/disable-hypertext-application-language-hal-in-json maybe this would be helpful in your case.

Comment: And how are you using `CrudRepository` to achieve this response? What object are you mapping it to? Usually `CrudRepository` is used as such `class MyObjectRepository implements CrudRepository<MyObject,Id> {...}` where MyObject is the object to which the response is mapped.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `CrudRepository`, you just need to adjust the object to which you are mapping it to. For instance, the way you used `CrudRepository` may be in this way:

```
class UserRepository implements CrudRepository<User,String> {...}
```

`String` is the class of the identifier (presumed *user_name*)

The `User` class could the be the following:

```
class User {
    @Id
    public String userName;
}
```

When returning this, the user will not contain the `_links` property.