# Spring-hateoas client not compatible with spring-boot-data-rest?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-hateoas

To try to understand the spring ecosystem, I'm building some toy projects on varios parts.

I've got a spring-boot-data-rest service working as expected ([code here](https://github.com/afaulconbridge/myspringbootexamples/tree/cc2eadd6b1504cbf86428922afcbbbde20b5a05b/17datah2rest)) and I am building a spring-boot and spring-hateoas client to access it ([code here](https://github.com/afaulconbridge/myspringbootexamples/tree/cc2eadd6b1504cbf86428922afcbbbde20b5a05b/18datah2restclient))

BUT for some reason I don't understand the client doesn't see the links that the server has.

This is what the JSON the service serves looks like:

```
{
    "firstName": "Alice",
    "lastName": "Foo",
    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/people/1"
        },
        "person": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/people/1"
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code the client is using to query the service:

```
    //now use a GET to get it back
    ResponseEntity<Resource<Person>> getResult = rest.exchange(
            "http://localhost:8080/people/1", HttpMethod.GET, null,
            new ParameterizedTypeReference<Resource<Person>>() {
            });

    //check the links on the response
    log.info("getResult "+getResult);
    log.info("getResult.getBody"+getResult.getBody());
    //uh oh, no links...
    log.info("getResult.getLink(\"self\")"+getResult.getBody().getLink("self"));
    log.info("getResult.getLink(\"self\").getHref()"+getResult.getBody().getLink("self").getHref());
```

And I am using Spring boot 1.4.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT version for both.

Is this a problem with my code or is this a bug somewhere? Any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @zeroflagL pointed out, the client as no idea about HAL.

The solution is more complicated and draws on the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/23271778/932342 to register an additional HTTPMessageConverter to the RestTemplate to handle "application/hal+json" content.

```
    RestTemplate rest = new RestTemplate();

    //need to create a new message converter to handle hal+json
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
    mapper.registerModule(new Jackson2HalModule());
    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
    converter.setSupportedMediaTypes(MediaType.parseMediaTypes("application/hal+json"));
    converter.setObjectMapper(mapper);

    //add the new converters to the restTemplate
    //but make sure it is BEFORE the exististing converters
    List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters = rest.getMessageConverters();
    converters.add(0,converter);
    rest.setMessageConverters(converters);
```

Comment: The first part is basically what happens when you add `@EnableHypermediaSupport`. But that doesn't affect the `RestTemplate`, only Spring MVC. So unfortunately you are right, you have to do that yourself (yet).

Answer (score 2):

You didn't enable support for HAL. You server uses Spring Data REST, which [uses HAL](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#repository-resources.resource-discoverability) as default. The client, on the other hand, has no idea about HAL. You can add support by adding `@EnableHypermediaSupport`:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableHypermediaSupport(type = HypermediaType.HAL)
public class Application {
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but unfortunately it doens't work for me - I think that annotation is for use on the server? It did put me on track to a solution anyway though!